# Mysql procedure sum

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sum

I cannot remember how to do a basic `SUM` in a SQL proceedure, can anybody remind me quickly please?

```
drop procedure if exists pCaCalculateCcyFluc;
delimiter //

create procedure pCaCalculateCcyFluc(
  IN  pPrice                DECIMAL(10,6),
  IN  pPricePrev            DECIMAL(10,6),
  OUT pCcyFluc              DECIMAL(10,6)  
)

MODIFIES SQL DATA
COMMENT 'calculate fluctuation'
begin

  pCcyFluc = (pPricePrev - pPrice)/pPrice;
  --
end;
//

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the [SUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) Function:

```
SELECT SUM(TableName.ColumnName)
   FROM TableName
   JOIN TableName ON TableName.ColumnName = TableName.ColumnName
   GROUP BY TableName.ColumnName;
```

Check out these [examples](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-sum-function.htm).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand the sum function. Perhaps I have phrased the question wrongly. The variables are fed into the procedure. I do not want to select them from a table. I want to call pCaCalculateCcyFlu('1.5', '1', pCcyFluc) and for it to output 0.333333

Comment: Sorry about that. Thinking again. :)